# How to insert values into SQL table?

Tags: sql

Code:

```
declare @startdate date = '2020-07-01';
declare @enddate date = '2020-07-31';

with dates as 
(
    select @startdate as orderdate
    union all 
    select dateadd(dd, 1, orderdate)
    from dates
    where dateadd(dd, 1, orderdate) <= @enddate
)
select * 
from dates
```

This code is displaying 2020-07-01 to 2020-07-31 dates list. How can I insert these values into table1? Thank you...

Comment: Which columns does your table have? Please tag your DBMS

Comment: I have only one column orderdate in that column I'm getting dates list and I'm using sql database. Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment there is one column only in table1, that's a simple insert into command at the end:

```
declare @startdate date='2020-07-01';
declare @enddate date='2020-07-31';

with dates as 
(select @startdate as orderdate
union all 
select DATEADD(dd,1,orderdate)
from dates
where DATEADD(dd,1,orderdate)<=@enddate)

insert into table1 select orderdate from dates;
```

See the sample here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KKSmkGNY)

This answer assumes you are using a SQL Server database because otherwise your question doesn't make sense to me. You should please tag your DBMS anyway.

"DBMS" means "Database Management System", for example this can be a Oracle DB, MySQL DB etc. Your comment "I use a SQL database" doesn't tell us which DBMS you use.